# Regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I've created a search system here = https://www.secondhandboards.com/productsresultsbrands.php

using Algolia Instantsearchjs V2

There is a filter on the left hand side were users can filter the products based on the size of a product.  However I cannot get the sizes to display in a suitable order.  We have various different combinations of sizes.  Some are in ft and inches such as 5'6" and some are text values such as S,M,L,XL and others are just numerical.  The numerical items are fine but when it comes to the ft and inches it shows or example:

5'10"
5'1"
5'2"
5'3"

So the 5'10" is coming before the 5'1" value.

My existing function is:

```
sortBy: function(a, b) {
return parseInt(a.name, 10) - parseInt(b.name, 10);
},
```

but not really achieving the desired outcome.

Has anyone got any pointers or examples of how I can implement regular expressions to get this list of sizes sorting correctly. I've never used regular expressions before.

Any help would be really appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `parseInt(`5'10"`,10) = 5`. parseInt stops at the first symbol that cannot be part of a number. Therefore all your examples are simply evaluated as `5 - 5`.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are for parsing text, not for comparing values. They are completely the wrong task for this job... unless you want to use them to process the values and see if they are indeed feet-and-inches measurements.

```
function isFeetAndInches(input) {
    // returns an array [feet,inches] if the input is such, false otherwise
    var match = input.match(/^(\d+)'(\d+)"$/);
    if( match) return [match[1],match[2]];
    return false;
}
```

Now you can compare:

```
var afi = isFeetAndInches(a),
    bfi = isFeetAndInches(b);
if( afi && bfi) {
    return afi[0] - bfi[0] || afi[1] - bfi[1];
}
// else try some other comparison because they aren't both feet-and-inches.
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to sort an array with those measurements.
Then one could use split in the callback function of the sort.

```js
var str = '6\'1" 5\'10" 5\'3" 5\'2" 5\'1" 4\'2"';
console.log(str);

let arr = str.match(/\b\d+'\d+"/g);

arr.sort(function(a,b) {const x = a.split(/\D+/), y = b.split(/\D+/); return x[0] - y[0] || x[1] - y[1]});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution seems to be to split by `'` and compare using a numeric `localeCompare`:

```js
var sizes = ["6'10\"", "4'10\"", "5'2\"", "5'10\"", "5'1\"", "5'3\""];
var sortedSizes = sizes
  .slice(0)
  .sort(function(a, b) {
    var A = a.split("'"),
      B = b.split("'");
    return A[0].localeCompare(B[0], [], {
      numeric: true
    }) || A[1].localeCompare(B[1], [], {
      numeric: true
    });
  });
console.log(sizes);
console.log(sortedSizes);
```